# How to compile the floating computation of DSPStone on X86 Architecture?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, benchmarking

I want to use this benchmark to evaluate my optimization in compiler.

I can compile **int computation** of DSPStone on X86 architecture, but the other cannot.

The error is the type of main function is float.

I know it is not allowed in X86 architecture, so I want to know if there are other ways to compile it on X86.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create a float function and call it with your main function. Please read some C tutorials.

I suggest this one: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm

```
float computation(float f);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float test = 3.14;
    test = computation(test);
    return 0;
}

float computation(float f) {
    f = f + f;
    return f;
}
```